# How to express many pairs of parents in English?

Tags: word-usage

There is no word **parents** found in oxford dictionary, but "**parent**" [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/parent#parent__4)

> **parent**: a person’s father or mother

Then how to express many pairs of parents in English?

*Can we say 2 or 3 pairs of parents?*

Googling "**pairs of parents**" return about [300K results](https://www.google.com/search?q=pairs%20of%20parents&oq=pairs%20of%20parents&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1055j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22pairs%20of%20parents%22)

Comment: Are you saying there is no plural of "parent"?

Comment: @user3169, Yes, there is no "**parents**" entry in oxford dictionary

Comment: IF you trying to talk about the group of people attending, for example, a Parent Teacher Association meeting, you might say, there were ***many parents*** in attendance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *two or three pairs of parents* is natural and grammatical.

The dictionary you link to says that *parent* is usually in the plural, and the example sentences it gives use the plural. It is a regular plural, formed by adding an *s*. Many times dictionaries will not list the plural form if it is not irregular.

Comment: I think I would tend to say ***sets of parents*** for some reason even though they are, by definition, pairs.

Answer (score 1):

**Parents** is a perfectly good word. It is the plural of **parent**.

**Multiple parents** is a term used to acknowledge the different roles and relationships a person can have with a child.

There are several types of **parents**, however. A person can have, and only have, two **biological parents**, from which the genetic makeup of the child in derived. [NB: at least at the time of this writing]

There are also **step parents** who have a legal but not biological relationship with the child.

There are also **psychological parents** who can have a **pastoral** or **emotionally supportive** relationship with the child.

Currently the legal profession is struggling to keep up with the available technology.

One could say **pairs of parents**, however there is an underlying assumption in that phrase that **parents occur in pairs**. If a **gay** or **lesbian** couple have a child, presumably there would be **three parents** involved, two of the same sex and one of the opposite sex.